# How to find $k$ in $6^{k} \equiv 2 \mod {13}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Find for which $k$ is $6^{k} \equiv 2 \mod {13}$

I'm having trouble with these types of question in my cryptography class. This is part of Diffie–Hellman algorithm for calculating a shared key.

I know that this can be written as discrete logarithm $\log_{6}{k}$ in $Z^{*}_{13}$ but that is all I could manage to do.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trial and error, since the modulus is small.

If the modulus is larger then the problem is believed to be computationally difficult - this is the whole point of Diffie-Hellman!

Comment: Oh, so you are telling that that my primitive(cave-man?) solution is not that bad? Yay!

Comment: Sadly, I don't think we are very far ahead of the cavemen on this particular problem...  (Subject to correction - I am not at all an expert in the topic.)

Comment: Ah, well okay then. Everything in life isn't in $P$

Comment: @Sabyasachi Well, this _is_ $P$, but when running so large numbers, even $P$ gets difficult. It is $E$ on the number of _digits_ of the input, not on the specific numbers themselves.

Comment: @Arthur it looks like computing $6^k$ should be exponential in $k$ no?

Comment: Oh, you're using proper methods, not a caveman approach to calculating $6^k$ then. I just brute forced that(well if cavemen had python)

Comment: @Sabyasachi Even as a caveman, calculating $6^k$ is just a whole lot of "times $6$" operations, which only gets more complicated as the number of digits grow, and those grow polynomially  (even linearly) with $k$.

Comment: @Arthur oh yes, you're right. It *is* linear in $k$. My bad.

Comment: @Sabyasachi I think it's quadratic, but at least it's polynomial.

Comment: @Arthur Assuming that multiplication is a constant time operation, this should be linear right?

Comment: @Sabyasachi But it's not, multiplying $6$ with $6$ is a lot easier than multiplying $6$ with $3,656,158,440,062,976$.

Comment: @Arthur Fair enough, I was just abstracting a little. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 1):

(New to this, someone probably has a better solution, you should wait before accepting)

By Fermat's little theorem, $$6^{12}\equiv1\pmod{13}$$

Therefore the powers of $6$ modulo 13 must cycle in sets of at most $12$.

Now, we just check by hand and get

$$6^5\equiv2\pmod{13}$$

Thus $k=12t+5$ for all $t\in\Bbb Z$

Because,

$$6^{12t+c}\equiv 6^c\left(6^{12}\right)^t\equiv 6^c \pmod{13}$$

Comment: "at most" $12$ does not mean $12$ is the order of $6\pmod{13}$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee no not necessarily, but $$6^{12t+c}\equiv 6^c\left(6^{12}\right)^t\equiv 6^c \pmod{13}$$. I should probably add that in.

Answer (score 0):

As $\displaystyle2^4=3\pmod{13}, 2=6^k=2^k\cdot3^k=2^k\cdot(2^4)^k=2^{5k}$

$\implies 2^{5k}\equiv2\iff2^{5k-1}\equiv1$

Now, $2^6=64\equiv-1\pmod{13}\implies$ord$_{13}2=12$ which must divide $5k-1$

$\displaystyle\implies5k\equiv1\pmod{12}\equiv1+24\iff k\equiv5\pmod{12}$ as $(5,12)=1$

Comment: Note: From $2^4\equiv 3$ it is already obvious that $2^5\equiv 6$

Comment: @MarkBennet, Agreed. But, in any case, we need to determine ord$_{13}2$

Answer (score 0):

You can also try dividing by $6$ noting that $6\times -2=-12\equiv 1$ mod $13$, so that dividing by $6$ is equivalent to multiplying by $-2$ so

$6^{k}\equiv 2$

$6^{k-1}\equiv -4$

$6^{k-2}\equiv 8$

$6^{k-3}\equiv -16\equiv -3$

$6^{k-4}\equiv 6$

$6^{k-5}\equiv -12\equiv 1$

Hence $k=5$ will do. Of course this trick to simplify the arithmetic is not always available.